# $g_{n}(x):=max \lbrace f_{1}(x),....\rbrace$ uniformly convergent if $\lbrace f_{n} \rbrace_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ uniformly bounded and equicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, continuity, uniform-convergence

Let $\lbrace f_{n} \rbrace_{n \in  \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of functions with real values which is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous in a metric space $X$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we define the following  functions $g_{n}:X \to \mathbb{R}$:

$$g_{n}(x):=max \lbrace f_{1}(x), f_{2}(x),....,f_{n}(x)\rbrace$$

For each $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that the sequence $\lbrace g_{n} \rbrace_{n \in  \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly convergent.

Since $\lbrace f_{n} \rbrace_{n \in  \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly bouded there is an $M$ such that $|f_{n}(x)| \leq M$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in X$. Also, as this sequence is also equicontinuous on $X$ we have that for every $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that if for every $x,y \in X$ and $d_{X}(x,y) < \delta$, then $d_{\mathbb{R}}(f_{n}(x), f_{n}(y)) < \epsilon$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

First and foremost, we need to find the pointwise limit of the sequence $\lbrace g_{n} \rbrace_{n \in  \mathbb{N}}$. Its not difficult to see this an incresing sequences, so that  $f_{n} \leq f_{n+1}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. On the other hand, since $\lbrace f_{n} \rbrace_{n \in  \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly bounded this sequence of functions is bounded. So by some well known sequence theorem we got that $\lbrace g_{n} \rbrace_{n \in  \mathbb{N}} \to sup (\lbrace f_{n} \rbrace_{n \in  \mathbb{N}})=s$ right? Still Im not sure how to prove than $\lbrace g_{n} \rbrace_{n \in  \mathbb{N}}$ uniformly converges to $s$ :/

Comment: It is $g_n$ and not $f_n$ that is increasing. But this indeed gives you *pointwise* convergence to $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} g_n(x)$. And in the beginning it should be $x \in X$ and not $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I have another question: Is $X$ compact?

Comment: Thanks for checking out my question. No, I don´t have $X$ is compact. Im not sure if I can proceed without having $X$ compact? @Meowdog

Comment: Please double check the definition of "equicontinuity". I remember that $\delta$ is allowed to depend on $\varepsilon$ and $x$ but not $n$. However, it seems that you assume that $\delta$ depends on $\varepsilon$ only. In that case, many authors call it "uniform equicontinuous", which is a much stronger condition.

Comment: According to wikipedia the propiety is defined for every function in the family. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity#cite_note-RS29-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma 1: Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. Let $f_{n}:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.
If $\{f_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is equicontinuous, then it is uniformly
equicontinuous.

Proof of Lemma 1: Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. For each $x\in X$,
there exists $\delta_{x}>0$ such that $|f_{n}(y)-f_{n}(x)|<\varepsilon$
whenever $y\in B(x,\delta_{x})$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Note that
$\{B(x,\delta_{x}/2)\mid x\in X\}$ is an open covering of the compact
set $X$, so it admits a finite subcover $\{B(x_{i},\delta_{x_{i}}/2)\mid i=1,\ldots,m\}$.
Let $\delta=\min_{1\leq i\leq m}\delta_{x_{i}}>0.$ Let $y_{1,}y_{2}\in X$
be arbitrary such that $d(y_{1},y_{2})<\delta$. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$
be arbitrary. Choose $i$ such that $y_{1}\in B(x_{i},\delta_{i})$,
then
\begin{eqnarray*}
d(y_{2},x_{i}) & \leq & d(y_{2},y_{1})+d(y_{1},x_{i})\\
 & < & \delta+\frac{1}{2}\delta_{x_{i}}\\
 & \leq & \delta_{x_{i}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Clearly, we also have $d(y_{1},x_{i})<\delta_{x_{i}}.$ Therefore,
$|f_{n}(y_{1})-f_{n}(y_{2})|\leq|f_{n}(y_{1})-f_{n}(x_{i})|+|f_{n}(x_{i})-f_{n}(y_{2})|<2\varepsilon.$
Hence, $\{f_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is uniformly equicontinuous.

---

Lemma 2: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $f_{n}:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.
Suppose that $\{f_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is equicontinuous. For
each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $g_{n}:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
$g_{n}=\max\{f_{1},f_{2},\ldots,f_{n}\}$. Then $\{g_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
is equicontinuous.

Proof of Lemma 2: Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $x\in X$ be given. Choose
$\delta>0$ such that $|f_{n}(x)-f_{n}(y)|<\varepsilon$ whenever
$y\in B(x,\delta)$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $y\in B(x,\delta)$
and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. Choose $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such
that $g_{n}(x)=f_{k}(x)$. For any $j=1,\ldots,n$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{j}(y) & < & f_{j}(x)+\varepsilon\\
 & \leq & g_{n}(x)+\varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore $g_{n}(y)=\max_{1\leq j\leq n}f_{j}(y)<g_{n}(x)+\varepsilon$.
On the other hand,
\begin{eqnarray*}
g_{n}(y) & \geq & f_{k}(y)\\
 & > & f_{k}(x)-\varepsilon\\
 & = & g_{n}(x)-\varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
This shows that $|g_{n}(y)-g_{n}(x)|<\varepsilon$. Hence, $\{g_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
is equicontinuous.

---

Now, we go back to your question and prove the following:

Proposition: Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
let $f_{n}:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function. Define $g_{n}:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
by $g_{n}=\max\{f_{1},f_{2},\ldots,f_{n}\}$. Suppose that $\{f_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous, then the sequence of functions
$(g_{n})$ converges uniformly.

Proof of Proposition: Choose $M>0$ such that $|f_{n}(x)|\leq M$
for all $x\in X$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Note that for each $x\in X$,
$(g_{n}(x))_{n}$ is bounded and monotonic increasing, so $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g_{n}(x)$
exists. Define $g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g_{n}(x)$.
Firstly, we go to show that $g$ is continuous (actually uniformly continuous. However, we do not need this fact at this moment). By Lemma 1 and Lemma
2, $\{g_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is uniformly equicontinuous. Let
$x\in X$ and $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Choose $\delta>0$ such that
$|g_{n}(s)-g_{n}(t)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $d(s,t)<\delta$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Let $y\in B(x,\delta)$ be arbitrary, then for each $n$, $|g_{n}(y)-g_{n}(x)|<\varepsilon$.
Letting $n\rightarrow\infty$, we obtain $|g(y)-(x)|\leq\varepsilon$.
This shows that $g$ is continuous at an arbitrary point $x$.

---

We go to prove that $g_{n}\rightarrow g$ uniformly by contradiction.
Suppose the contrary that $(g_{n})$ does not converges to $g$ uniformly,
then may choose $\varepsilon>0$ such that
$$
\forall N\exists n\geq N\exists x\in X\left(|g_{n}(x)-g(x)|\geq\varepsilon\right).
$$
Put $N=1$, we obtain $n_{1}\geq1$ and $x_{1}\in X$ such that $|g_{n_{1}}(x_{1})-g(x_{1})|\geq\varepsilon$.
Put $N=n_{1}+1$, we obtain $n_{2}\geq n_{1}+1$ and $x_{2}\in X$
such that $|g_{n_{2}}(x_{2})-g(x_{2})|\geq\varepsilon$. Continue
the process indefinitely, we obtain sequences $(n_{k})_{k}$, $(x_{k})$
such that $n_{1}<n_{2}<\ldots$ and $|g_{n_{k}}(x_{k})-g(x_{k})|\geq\varepsilon$
for all $k$. (If we want to argue it formally, we need to invoke
the Recursion Theorem). Since $X$ is compact, we may choose a subsequence
$(x_{k_{l}})$ of $(x_{k})$ such that $x_{k_{l}}\rightarrow x$ for
some $x\in X$. To simplify notation, we denote $h_{l}=g_{n_{k_{l}}}$
and $y_{l}=x_{k_{l}}$, for $l\in\mathbb{N}$. Hence, $|h_{l}(y_{l})-g(y_{l})|\geq\varepsilon$
for all $l$ and $y_{l}\rightarrow x$.

On the other hand, note that $\{g_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is equicontinuous
(by Lemma 2), which implies that the sub-family $\{h_{l}\mid l\in\mathbb{N}\}$
is also equicontinuous. By Lemma 1, $\{h_{l}\mid l\in\mathbb{N}\}$
is uniformly equicontinuous. Therefore, there exists $\delta_{1}>0$
such that $|h_{l}(s)-h_{l}(t)|<\varepsilon/10$ whenever $d(s,t)<\delta_{1}$
and $l\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $g$ is continous at $x$, there exists
$\delta_{2}>0$ such that $|g(t)-g(x)|<\varepsilon/10$ whenever $t\in B(x,\delta_{2})$.
Since $y_{l}\rightarrow x$, we can choose $L_{1}\in\mathbb{N}$ such
that $d(y_{l},x)<\min(\delta_{1},\delta_{2})$ whenever $l\geq L_{1}$.
Note that $h_{l}(x)\rightarrow g(x)$, so there exists $L_{2}$ such
that $|h_{l}(x)-g(x)|<\varepsilon/10$ whenever $l\geq L_{2}$. Put
$l=\max(L_{1},L_{2})$, then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\varepsilon & \leq & \left|h_{l}(y_{l})-g(y_{l})\right|\\
 & \le & \left|h_{l}(y_{l})-h_{l}(x)\right|+\left|h_{l}(x)-g(x)\right|+\left|g(x)-g(y_{l})\right|\\
 & < & \varepsilon/10+\varepsilon/10+\varepsilon/10\\
 & = & \frac{3\varepsilon}{10},
\end{eqnarray*}
which is a contradiction.

In the above, have used the following facts:

(1) $l\geq L_{1}\Rightarrow d(y_{l},x)<\min(\delta_{1},\delta_{2})\leq\delta_{1}\Rightarrow|h_{l}(s)-h_{l}(t)|<\varepsilon/10$,

(2) $l\geq L_{2}\Rightarrow|h_{l}(x)-g(x)|<\varepsilon/10$,

(3) $l\geq L_{1}\Rightarrow d(y_{l},x)<\min(\delta_{1},\delta_{2})\leq\delta_{2}\Rightarrow\left|g(x)-g(y_{l})\right|<\varepsilon/10$.

Comment: Though your proof maybe right for compact sets, the OP does not mention that $X$ is compact. For the compact case, where you can shorten the proof by appealing to Dini's theorem (or showing the arguments behind Dini's theorem)

Comment: If $X$ is not compact, I prove that the conclusion does not hold. See my other post. OP asked me for help when $X$ is compact.

Comment: I know, I am just saying that your additional proof for the compact case maybe considerably shorten by the ways of Dini. The advantage is that the arguments of monotonicity work nicely here and the OP may get a more direct and clear argument.

Comment: The reasons of not invoking any other theorem are:
1. I try to make the proof self-contained because not everyone knows Dini's Theorem or Ascoli-Arzela Theorem.
I try to invoke as less theorems as possible.

2. The proof by contradiction demonstrated here still works as long as $(g_n)$ converges pointwisely and $\{g_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is equicontinuous. Although we have $g_1 \leq g_2 \leq \ldots$ in this problem,
this condition may not hold in other problem.

Comment: That is all right! A short of Dini's will make your answer more rounded. But that is just my opinion.

Comment: The details and insight in your proof were really clear and helpful.  But Oliver Diaz made me curious about Dini´s Theorem. To use Dini we must prove that the  each function from the increasing sequence $g_{n}$ is continuous and that $lim_{n_{\infty}}g_{n}=g$ is continuous. You already proved that $g$ is continuous, and you also proved by Lemma $2$ that the sequence $g_{n}$ is equicontinuous. But  from Lemma 1 $g_{n}$ is  uniformly continuous since $g_{n}$ is equicontinuous. So if the sequence is uniformly continuous, then each function from the sequence is continuous? @DannyPak-KeungChan

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if $X$ is not compact, the proposition is false. Consider
the following example:

Let $X=[0,\infty)$ equipped with the usual metric. For each $n$,
let $f_{n}:X\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ be defined by
$$
f_{n}(x)=\begin{cases}
1, & \mbox{if }x\in[0,n]\\
\mbox{linear }, & \mbox{if }x\in(n,n+1)\\
0 & \mbox{if }x\in[n+1,\infty)
\end{cases}.
$$
Clearly $\{f_{n}\mid f\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is uniformly bounded and uniformly equicontinuous.
Moreover, $f_{1}\leq f_{2}\leq\ldots$. Therefore $g_{n}=\max\{f_{1},\ldots,f_{n}\}=f_{n}$.
Clearly $g_{n}\rightarrow1$ pointwisely but the not uniformly.

Comment: Appreciate it so much! Wondering how I can see the sequence is uniformly convergent if $X$ is compact?

Comment: I think that you will have to prove equicontinuity of $g_n$. Then Arzelà-Ascoli gives you a subsequence that converges uniformly. Then, as we know that the only possible accumulation point is $sup_n g_n$, the entire sequence converges.